# Use 'pass' return value in another function in python

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I am using python 3.5. Function1 is :

```
def boolean_key_validation(dictionary, key):
    data = {}
    try:
        dictionary_value = dictionary[key]
    except KeyError:
        pass
    else:
        if dictionary_value == 'TRUE':
            data[key] = True
        elif dictionary_value == 'FALSE':
            data[key] = False
        else:
            raise ValueError("{} value should be either blank or 'TRUE'/'FALSE' only".format(key))
    return data[key] # not able to get the 'do_nothing' value here
```

Function 2 is :

```
def read_file(start_date, end_date, dictionary):
    read_data = {}
    files = File.objects.all()
    # ... #
    read_data['downloaded'] = boolean_key_validation(dictionary, 'downloaded')
    read_data['integrity'] = boolean_key_validation(dictionary, 'integrity')
    read_data['validation'] = boolean_key_validation(dictionary, 'validation')

    return files.filter(**read_data)
```

I want to filter my model 'File' based on the boolean values of 'downloaded', etc.
In function1 what I want is that if key is not present in dictionary this function1 should do nothing and my read_data dictionary in function2 should have no value for that key.

I have searched for similar problem but those are using 'pass' in conditional statements within some function.

EDIT:

following was the main function in which I have lots of boolean values input and I had to write separate try-catch for each key. Therefore, created the 'boolean_key_validation' to validate those lots of keys and shorten my main function. Here 'pass' is doing its job but my function1 is not able to give me this kind of return.

If key is not present in dictionary I just want it to omit from read_data.

```
def read_file(start_date, end_date, dictionary):
    read_data = {}
    files = File.objects.all()
    # try-catch for checking 'downloaded'.
    # have to write these conditions for other boolean values also and thats why created function1.
    try:
        dictionary_value = dictionary['downloaded']
    except KeyError:
        pass
    else:
        if dictionary_value.upper() == 'TRUE':
            read_data['downloaded'] = True
        elif dictionary_value.upper() == 'FALSE':
            read_data['downloaded'] = False
        else:
            raise ValueError("downloaded value should be either blank or 'TRUE'/'FALSE' only")
    # try catch for 'integrity' and 'validation' etc. #
     return files.filter(**read_data)
```

Comment: By no value for the key do you mean `None`.

Comment: No not None. I mean like my files.filter() in function2 will not have that key to apply filter on File model.

Comment: Why not just use `'downloaded' in dictionary.keys()`? This gives you the True/False value right away.

Comment: I will try this.

Comment: @Idlehands, if key is not present then I want it to omit to go in my filter(). True/False value will filter based on just these values. I have edited the question for full context. Let me know if its still not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are assigning the return value of `boolean_key_validation` without checking the value, the entry will anyways be created in the `read_data`dictionary even if its `None.`

What you can do is remove `key` with `None` values after constructing `read_data` dictionary

```
read_data = {k:v for k,v in read_data.items() if v is not None}
File.objects.filter(**read_data)
```

Another approach is to raise `KeyError` and `ValueError` in `boolean_key_validation` and capture it while populating `read_data.`

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is you over complicated things, but without knowing the full scope of what your code is supposed to do, it's hard to comment on it properly.

Either way, to achieve what you want, simply replace `pass` with `return None`, and now your `read_data` keys should only have 3 possible states: `True`, `False`, or `None.

```
def boolean_key_validation(dictionary, key):
    if key in dictionary.keys():
        if dictionary_value.upper() == 'TRUE':
            return True
        elif dictionary_value.upper() == 'FALSE':
            return False
        else:
            raise ValueError("{} value should be either blank or 'TRUE'/'FALSE' only".format(key))
    else:
        return None # return None if key is missing.
```

You don't need the `data = {}` at all if all you're returning is the `dictionary_value` being converted to a boolean type.  You might also want to use `.upper()` on your `dictionary_value` to eliminate case sensitivity.  I'm still not sure about the `raise ValueError` I'd feel you program should be actually handling this instead of just raising an error and terminating the program as a result.  But again, without knowing the intent it's hard to comment.

If your dictionary should ever only `TRUE/FALSE`, it'll make your life so much easier, you can even put this in a loop:

```
# ... #
    check_keys = lambda k: eval(dictionary[k].capitalize()) if k in dictionary.keys() else None
    key_list = ['downloaded', 'integrity', 'validation']
    for key in key_list:
        read_data[key] = check_keys(key)
```

Edit: With your last comment, I would simply update function 1 to assign the value to `read_data` instead of having it return a value to be assigned separately:

```
def assign_data(data, dictionary, key_list):
    for key in key_list:
        if key in dictionary.keys():
            if dictionary[key].upper() in ('TRUE', 'FALSE'):
                data[key] = eval(dictionary[key].capitalize())
            else:
                raise ValueError("{} value should be either blank or 'TRUE'/'FALSE' only".format(
                    key))  # Maybe handle this instead of raising error
```

Usage:

```
def read_file(start_date, end_date, dictionary):
    read_data = {}
    files = File.objects.all()
    # ... #
    keys = ['downloaded', 'integrity', 'validation']
    assign_data(read_data, dictionary, keys)

    return files.filter(**read_data)
```

Example:

```
dict = {1:'TRUE', 2: 'FALSE', 3: 'FALSE'}
keys = [1,2,3,4,5]
data = {}
assign_data(data,dict,keys)

# data = {1: True, 2: False, 3: False}
```

Comment: finally solved it. I modified my function1 as per your suggestion but finally ended up using @Bhavani solution. thanks for your time.

Comment: You're welcome.  Though I'd argue if all you want is True/False in your read_data, you should modify your function 1 to handling the assigning so that you don't have to manually remove the `None` values afterwards.  I've updated my answer with another suggestion, see my Edits.

Comment: The usage and example are good. I learned a new approach to same problem with this. Thanks for your kind efforts.